# nodeValue is null in VBScript

Tags: xml, vbscript

In VBScript, I have this XML document:

```
<m>
    <x>300001
        <y>10000294
            <z>2120300003</z>
            <z>2120300004</z>
        </y>
        <y>10000295
            <z>2120300003</z>
            <z>2120300006</z>
        </y>
        <y>10000296
            <z>2120300001</z>
        </y>
        <y>10000302
            <z>2120300002</z>
        </y>
    </x>
    <x>300048
        <y>10000294
            <z>2120300002</z>
        </y>
    </x>
</m>
```

and I'd like to get the values of each of the <y> elements themselves, and not anything under it, into an array to compare the value against another data set later on in a loop. I've done a simple test with outputting the value, and the nodeValue property is always null.

My current code is:

```
dim matrixArray, y, outputText
set matrixArray = oXml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("y")

outputText = ""   

for each y in matrixArray 
    outputText = outputText & ", " & y.nodeValue
next
```

In the above, y.nodeValue is null. If I use y.text, it outputs the text of the node and all the text of <y> element's subtree. Similarly, y.nodeTypedValue also outputs the same as y.text.
i.e. 1000029421203000032120300004, 1000029521203000032120300006, 100002962120300001, 100003022120300002, 100002942120300002

Note that I cannot change the structure of the XML document and must comply with it.

How do I just get the text of each of the <y> elements without getting any of the <z> element text under them?
i.e. 10000294, 10000295, 10000296, 10000302, 10000294

Comment: Seems there is no solution to this except to restructure the XML so that there is no text and child nodes under the <y> elements. The duplicate answers indicate that the <y> text should become an attribute if there are child nodes under it as well. Unfortunately, this isn't possible with the XML structure I posed in the question as it comes from another source that I cannot control. If I find a way, I'll answer it here in the comments.

Comment: The first linked post has a way, : get the y.text  (which contains z.text, `txt = y.Text`)  replace the z.text in it (`txt = Replace(txt, z.text, ""`) .  Only change is,,as you have multiple `z`'s the `replace`  should be done within a `for each z in y.SelectNodes("z")` loop.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that, but it wouldn't work in certain cases. Firstly it'll be slow with large data sets or deeper sub-trees. But the big fault in it is there's an issue where any concatenated values may somehow match a Z value, e.g. Y is 1212, and you have one Z which is 1212, you'll end up with an empty string, or your Y is 1050023, and you have two Z, 207101 and 23207, you'll end up with 10500101 instead of 1050023

Comment: @Krylion Isn't the text under `<y>` classed as another child `Node` called `#text`?

Comment: @user692942 is right, `y.childNodes(0).text` does give the required value.